# directory in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/config have no hard links?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, hardlink, proc, links

**Why the directories inside /proc/sys/net/ipv4/config have no hard links?**

```
ls -l /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x 0 root root 0 Dec 31 08:27 all
dr-xr-xr-x 0 root root 0 Dec 31 08:27 default
dr-xr-xr-x 0 root root 0 Dec 31 08:27 eth0
dr-xr-xr-x 0 root root 0 Dec 31 08:27 lo
```

Answer (score 1):

The directories in `/proc` do not really exist. It is a virtual filesystem with information which is generated on the fly.  *Hardlinks* have no place in them (and would not save any space if you could use them).

Answer (score 0):

The directories in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf` are neither hardlinks¹ nor softlinks¹. But that is of no interest.

The important thing is, that **procfs** (proc filesystem) is a **special filesystem**, usually mounted at /proc, that presents information about processes and other system information in a hierarchical file-like structure, providing a more convenient and standardized method for dynamically accessing process data held in the kernel.

In other words the procfs provides a method of communication between kernel space and user space. **The files in the procfs show the content of variables in kernel space.** And the kernel is the piece of software, that communicates with the hardware of the computer.

¹) As mdpc said, `ls -l` shows the link count in the first line. And that is zero in the procfs.

Answer (score 0):

In fact if you look at the link count, they are not links at all (`ls -l` shows link counts, in this case the link count is equal to zero).

Others have specified that files in `/proc`, are convenient for accessing selected kernel data easily and programatically.